# How to update records in a table with leading spaces?

Tags: informix

I have a table with n number of records and n number of columns. I want to add some leading spaces to the records in a particular column. How could I achieve this?

For ex:
If the column has record like `'AAAA'`, I want it like `'   AAA'` (few leading blank spaces).

Comment: Did you intend to lose one of the A's?  If so, which one?  What if the column contains `'BBB'` or `'XYZ'`?

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're looking for is a way to copy a column that is left-padded to the total number of bytes specified by length. You can achieved it by using [LPAD](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1563.htm).

But if what you want is just add one space regardless of the length you can straight forward do `" " | column_name`.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE TheAnonymousTable
   SET TheEponymousColumn = '    ' || TheEponymousColumn
 WHERE TheEponymousColumn[1,4] != '    '
```

That will work almost always.  Under some circumstances (if you're using a MODE ANSI database — if you're not sure, you aren't) and if you have data that is already within 4 spaces of the length of the column, you will get an error `-1279: Value exceeds string column length`.  In context, if you know the length of the column is, say, 32 and you are inserting 4 blanks, then you'd need to write this instead:

```
UPDATE TheAnonymousTable
   SET TheEponymousColumn = '    ' || TheEponymousColumn[1,28]
 WHERE TheEponymousColumn[1,4] != '    '
```